# Safely create new instance of EF Core DbContext

Tags: c#, security, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Sometimes in .NET Core there are cases when more than one `DbContext` is needed (Parallel database requests etc.).

Would it be safe to have any of these two solutions in my DbContext class?

```
    private static string _connectionString;

    private static string ConnectionString => 
        _connectionString ??= new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build().GetConnectionString("CoreConnection");

    public static CoreContext GetContext()
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CoreContext>()
            .UseNpgsql(ConnectionString)
            .Options;

        return new CoreContext(options);
    }
```

or

```
    private static IConfiguration _configuration;

    private static IConfiguration Configuration =>
        _configuration ??= new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

    private static string ConnectionString => 
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("CoreConnection");

    public static CoreContext GetContext()
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CoreContext>()
            .UseNpgsql(ConnectionString)
            .Options;

        return new CoreContext(options);
    }
```

I have read (for old ASP .NET) that you should avoid keeping sensitive data such as passwords and connection strings containing passwords in the application memory in plain text, since the memory might be hacked or dumped/saved after a crash.

Is this still true for .NET Core? (guess it should be)

Is it any safer to use `IConfiguration` or does it store the connection string in plain text in the memory also?

Is the global `IConfiguration` that can be used with DI in net core storing all `appsettings.json` file data in memory?

Is it more likely that memory would get hacked, then that a hacker might be able to read the `appsettings.json` information directly instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help.

> It is very important to dispose the DbContext after use. This ensures
> both that any unmanaged resources are freed, and that any events or
> other hooks are unregistered so as to prevent memory leaks in case the
> instance remains referenced. DbContext is not thread-safe. Do not
> share contexts between threads. Make sure to await all async calls
> before continuing to use the context instance. An
> InvalidOperationException thrown by EF Core code can put the context
> into an unrecoverable state. Such exceptions indicate a program error
> and are not designed to be recovered from.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/

This can also help:

> Never store passwords or other sensitive data in source code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=windows